# Abealian A of order $p^2q^3$ (distinct primes) contains an element of order $q^2$. Show all A that have a cyclic p-Sylow group

Tags: group-theory

I have the following practice problem:

Abealian group A of order $p^2q^3$ (distinct primes) contains an element of order $q^2$.

Show all A up to isomorphism that have a cyclic p-Sylow group:

I know that I have a p-Sylow groups of order $p^2$. So A must have an element of order $p^2$. So my answer is there is only one:

$Z_{p^2} \times Z_{q^2} \times Z_{q}$

Is this correct?

Comment: No it is not correct. Perhaps if you gave a reason why the Sylow-$q$-subgroup is what you say we could help.

Comment: 1. Why must $A$ have an element of order $p^2$? Why can $A$ not be $Z_p \times Z_p \times Z_{q^2} \times Z_q$? | 2. Why can't it be $Z_{p^2} \times Z_{q^3}$?

Comment: Ok, so it is all A that contain $Z_{q^2} \times Z_q$?